# Missing Comma, oracle ORA-00917

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

I have this code for inserting values into a oracle database, and I get "Missing comma" Exception, and I can't see from where it comes.

```
 "insert into comandadvd values('" + txt_idComanda.Text + "','" +
                    txtFormat.Text + "','" + "', to_date('" + txtData.Text + "','DDMMYYY')'" + txtIdTipPlata.Text + "','" + txtPret.Text + "')";
```

Alse here it is the Oracle code for it:

```
INSERT INTO ComandaDVD (Id_Comanda,Id_Format,Data_Comanda,Id_TipPlata,Pret)
VALUES ('1','1','12-11-2011','1','200');
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the command you gave an example of values or the actual command? This will fail badly if, say, `txtFormat.Text` ever contains `O'Leary` (or, indeed, `Robert'); DROP TABLE ComandaDvd; --`) -- please read up on SQL injection and parameterized commands.

Comment: does the insert statement work separately in the database and failing in c# code?

Comment: @JeroenMostert `Robert'); DROP TABLE ComandaDvd; --` will fail as Oracle (unlike some other RDBMSes) does not allow multiple statements in the same command.

Comment: @MT0: fair point, for this particular command -- though SQL injection is a real risk on Oracle as well, of course.

Comment: @JeroenMostert: [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/) :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You added extra comma before `to_date(` in your query. The corrected code as below:

```
"INSERT INTO ComandaDVD (Id_Comanda,Id_Format,Data_Comanda,Id_TipPlata,Pret) VALUES (" +
    "'" + txt_idComanda.Text + "', " +
    "'" + txtFormat.Text + "', " +
    "to_date('" + txtData.Text + "', 'DDMMYYY'), " +
    "'" + txtIdTipPlata.Text + "', " + 
    "'" + txtPret.Text + "')";
```

Comment: you were right Arulkumar. I completely forgot about parameters.

Answer (score 2):

- try this once

`"insert into comandadvd values('" + txt_idComanda.Text + "','" +
                txtFormat.Text + "','" + "' to_date('" + txtData.Text + "','DDMMYYY')'" + "','" + txtIdTipPlata.Text + "','" + txtPret.Text + "')";`

Answer (score 1):

The immediate cause of the error is in the

```
"','" + "', to_date('"
```

fragmanent. The best solution is using *parametrized* query:

```
  @"insert into comandadvd (
      Id_Comanda,
      Id_Format,
      Data_Comanda,
      Id_TipPlata,
      Pret)
    values ( 
      :prm_Id_Comanda,
      :prm_Id_Format,
      :prm_Data_Comanda,
      :prm_Id_TipPlata,
      :prm_Pret)";
```

In case that for whatever reason you can't use *parametrized* query, use *formatted* one:

```
   String.Format(
     @"insert into comandadvd (
         Id_Comanda,
         Id_Format,
         Data_Comanda,
         Id_TipPlata,
         Pret)
       values ( 
         {0},
         {1},
         to_date('{2}', 'DDMMYYY'),
         {3},
         {4})",
      txt_idComanda.Text,
      txtFormat.Text, 
      txtData.Text,
      txtIdTipPlata.Text,
      txtPret.Text);
```

The guiding principle is **Make your SQL readable**

Answer (score 0):

1. You have an extra comma before date. The date part `to_date` should not be inside quotes.
2. The date format is wrong. You mentioned `DD-MM-YYYY` in example.

Try this as I havn't tested it and let me know if you get error.

```
"insert into comandadvd values('" + txt_idComanda.Text + "','" + txtFormat.Text + "','" + "to_date('" 
+ txtData.Text + "','DD-MM-YYY')" + txtIdTipPlata.Text + "','" + txtPret.Text + "')";
```

Answer (score 0):

There appear to be multiple problems:

1. The biggest problem is that you did not run the code to see what it really does - witness the fact that the table name used in the code and the table name shown in the `SELECT` have different capitalization, and there's a field list in the posted `SELECT` which the code does not generate; therefore, the `SELECT` text you posted was obviously not generated by this code. If you had actually **run the code** and generated the INSERT statement you'd have found that it doesn't work as you *think* it does, and you could have fixed it yourself.
2. This code will put multiple commas before `to_date`.
3. The code will not generate a comma before `txtIdTipPlata.Text`.
4. `INSERT` statements should ALWAYS include a list of the names of the fields to be inserted.

Best of luck.

Comment: Oracle doesn't care about capitalization of object names unless double-quoted, so this is not a problem. Also, the code only provides values to be inserted, there are no column names. The values in the code match exactly the column names from the select statement. So that is not a problem either. The extra comma in the concarenated string is indeed the problem, the OP probably meant to add it after the date and before idtipplata, as you noted.